# Regex expression to get numbers without parentheses ()

Tags: javascript, regex, string-matching

I'm trying to create a regex that will select the numbers/numbers with commas(if easier, can trim commas later) that do not have a parentheses after and not the numbers inside the parentheses should not be selected either.

Used with the JavaScript's String.match method

Example strings

```
9(296,178),5,3(123),10
10,9(296,178),2,5,3(123),3(124,125)
10,7,5(296,293,444,1255),3(218),2,4
```

What i have so far:

```
/((^\d+[^\(])|(,\d+,)|(,*\d+$))/gm
```

I tried this in regex101 and underlined the numbers i would like to match and x on the one that should not.

[image: I tried this in regex101 and underlined the numbers i would like to match and x on the one that should not]

Comment: It might be worth using a more powerful tool than regex alone for this. Could you tell us more of the context these strings come from and the regex engine you use? Also, are we going to have nested parenthesis, or it's only one level of depth?

Comment: Yes its used with the JavaScript's String.match method

Comment: @MathieuCAROFF There is only one level of depth.

Comment: I'd just match what you do not need (negative contexts) and then match and capture what you need, the so-called ["best regex trick ever"](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html#thetrick).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could start with a substitution to remove all the unwanted parts:

```
/\d*\(.*?\),?//gm
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cJMazr/1)

This leaves you with

```
5,10
10,2,5,
10,7,2,4
```

which makes the matching pretty straight forward:

```
/(\d+)/gm
```

If you want it as a single match expression you could use a negative lookbehind:

```
/(?<!\([\d,]*)(\d+)(?:,|$)/gm
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/psJZUf/1) - and here's the same matching expression as a runnable javascript (skeleton code borrowed from [Wiktor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74208452/7582247)):

```js
const text = `9(296,178),5,3(123),10
10,9(296,178),2,5,3(123),3(124,125)
10,7,5(296,293,444,1255),3(218),2,4`;
const matches = Array.from(text.matchAll(/(?<!\([\d,]*)(\d+)(?:,|$)/gm), x=>x[1])
console.log(matches);
```

Comment: Smart approach, I have just played with a [lookahead (demo)](https://regex101.com/r/pHQm9D/1) but this is more efficient.

Comment: @bobblebubble Thanks! I added a version using a negative lookbehind too.

Answer (score 3):

Here, I'd recommend the so-called ["best regex trick ever"](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html#thetrick): just match what you do not need (negative contexts) and then match and capture what you need, and grab the captured items only.

If you want to match integer numbers that are not matched with `\d+\([^()]*\)` pattern (a number followed with a parenthetical substring), you can match this pattern or match *and capture* the `\d+`, one or more digit matching pattern, and then simply grab Group 1 values from matches:

```js
const text = `9(296,178),5,3(123),10
10,9(296,178),2,5,3(123),3(124,125)
10,7,5(296,293,444,1255),3(218),2,4`;
const matches = Array.from(text.matchAll(/\d+\([^()]*\)|(\d+)/g), x=> x[1] ?? "").filter(Boolean)
console.log(matches);
```

*Details*:

- `text.matchAll(/\d+\([^()]*\)|(\d+)/g)` - matches one or more digits (`\d+`) + `(` (with `\(`) + any zero or more chars other than `(` and `)` (with `[^()]*`) + `\)` (see `\)`), or (`|`) one or more digits captured into Group 1 (`(\d+)`)
- `Array.from(..., x=> x[1] ?? "")` - gets Group 1 value, or, if not assigned, just adds an empty string
- `.filter(Boolean)` - removes empty strings.

Answer (score 0):

#### Using several replacement regexes

```js
var textA = `9(296,178),5,3(123),10
10,9(296,178),2,5,3(123),3(124,125)
10,7,5(296,293,444,1255),3(218),2,4
`
console.log('A', textA)

var textB = textA.replace(/\(.*?\),?/g, ';')
console.log('B', textB)

var textC = textB.replace(/^\d+|\d+$|\d*;\d*/gm, '')
console.log('C', textC)

var textD = textC.replace(/,+/g, ' ').trim(',')
console.log('D', textD)
```

#### With a loop

Here is a solution which splits the lines on comma and loops over the pieces:

```js
var inside = false;
var result = [];

`9(296,178),5,3(123),10
10,9(296,178),2,5,3(123),3(124,125)
10,7,5(296,293,444,1255),3(218),2,4
`.split("\n").map(line => {
  let pieceArray = line.split(",")
  pieceArray.forEach((piece, k) => {
    if (piece.includes('(')) {
      inside = true
    } else if (piece.includes(')')) {
      inside = false
    } else if (!inside && k > 0 && k < pieceArray.length-1 && !pieceArray[k-1].includes(')')) {
      result.push(piece)
    }
  })
})

console.log(result)
```

It does print the expected result: `["5", "7"]`